# Jquery Superbox

Tags: jquery

```
  $('.finalLink').html("<a href='"+links[$(this).val()]+"' rel='superbox[iframe][700x500]' title='Final Link'> Click to Follow</a>");
```

I am trying to make a link that opens in a superbox mode. Tried lightbox with same results. The links work but just goes to the site. If I statically right the link, it works..

Any thoughts? This is driving me bonkers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess as i do not have knowledge on superbox or lightbox...

There is a binding on anchor tags for a click event, which is done when the document is loaded. There after any new anchor tags added to the page (such as what you have done above) is not applicable to the click event.

Maybe try and "re-initialize" superbox/lightbox after you change the html of .finalLink by calling the plugin again on that specific anchor tag.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. Re instantiating the plugin fixed my problem!! WOOT :)

Answer (score 2):

Since `$.superbox()` runs against all `<a rel="superbox....">` elements  present *when it was run*, you need to handle newly created elements separately, like this:

```
$('.finalLink').html("<a href='"+links[$(this).val()]+"' title='Final Link'> Click to Follow</a>")
   .find('a').superbox('iframe', { boxWidth: "700", boxHeight: "500" });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you are creating this link after the page has loaded. Superbox (or whatever box you're using) crawls the site on DOM-ready. Since your script is likely to run *after* that, your link cannot be bound by superbox.